# Do I need to use a thread? GUI + simple web scraping

Tags: multithreading, user-interface

I'm writing an application processing some webscraping and informing the user about the results, there is a need do repeat the webscraping over a time.
I'm doing the gui in Qt with PySide, it is quite simple GUI with QStackedWidget.

I'm wondering if there is a need to use threads in such simple application?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your GUI to be responsive while it's downloading things from the web, then absolutely you need threads. You need one for the GUI, and one for background network access.

If you don't do this, then you'll find that your application will lock up while it's doing its network thing. You'll probably still be able to move the window around, but it won't redraw itself or respond to any clicks.

Comment: One more question. You are talking about downloading from web, but I guess in other challenging tasks the problem will also occur? If not, why it is so? Network tasks are so demanding?

Comment: @user4175226 network tasks are a good example of where threading is needed because they're not instantaneous, and in fact the time taken isn't even predictable (network latency, host down, etc.). But it also applies to long-running calculations, or anything that you can't be sure will be done pretty much instantaneously.